# Angular ui-router $urlRouterProvider not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

```
function routeConfig($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
      .state('main', {
        url: '/main',
        templateUrl: 'app/pages/main/main.html',
        title: 'Main',
        sidebarMeta: {
          icon: 'ion-android-home',
          order: 0,
        },
      }).state('main.list', {
        url: '/list',
        templateUrl: 'app/pages/main/list/coinList.html',
        title: 'Main',
        controller: 'coinListCtrl',
        resolve: {
          coinMarketData: function(MarketCapService) {
            return MarketCapService.getCrypto();
          }
        }
      }).state('main.detail', {
        url: '/detail/:symbol',
        templateUrl: 'app/pages/main/detail/coinDetail.html',
        title: 'Main',
        controller: "coinDetailCtrl",
      });
      $urlRouterProvider.when('/main','/mail/list');
}
```

I have one main state and two child states as main.list and main.details. Using $urlRouterProvider service i want to go to main.list state by default. But it seems the command - `$urlRouterProvider.when('/main','/mail/list');`
is not working at all.

Comment: If you don't want make '/main' accesible you could try to define the 'main' state as abstract state.  https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/nested-states-%26-nested-views#abstract-states

Comment: When i added abstract:true, then i could not navigate to its child. Console threw - Error: Cannot transition to abstract state 'main'. Basically my urlrouterprovider isn't routing it to child state

Answer (score 0):

The code started working when i put `$urlRouterProvider.when('/main','/mail/list');` above the registration of states, like this:-

```
function routeConfig($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.when('/main','/mail/list');
  $stateProvider
      .state('main', {
        url: '/main',
        templateUrl: 'app/pages/main/main.html',
        title: 'Main',
        sidebarMeta: {
          icon: 'ion-android-home',
          order: 0,
        },
      }).state('main.list', {
        url: '/list',
        templateUrl: 'app/pages/main/list/coinList.html',
        title: 'Main',
        controller: 'coinListCtrl',
        resolve: {
          coinMarketData: function(MarketCapService) {
            return MarketCapService.getCrypto();
          }
        }
      }).state('main.detail', {
        url: '/detail/:symbol',
        templateUrl: 'app/pages/main/detail/coinDetail.html',
        title: 'Main',
        controller: "coinDetailCtrl",
      });

}
```

Though i would still like to know why? This might be due to lack of JS knowledge though, but still enlighten me..